# SQL Complex Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I'm trying to generate a query that will do the following:

I have an offer catalog table that has [Id, term, loanamount, interestrate], for every id there are multiple offers, i.e. every customer gets multiple offers. I'm trying to retrieve a dataset with the offer for each id that has [Id, max(term), max(loanamount)] and then the interest rate for the offer with the max(term) and max(loanamount) the way the I view it is the following:

```sql
SELECT a.Id as oppId, 
       a.MAX(Term) as maxTerm, 
       a.MAX(LoanAmount) as maxAmount, 
       b.InterestRate 
FROM table a 
JOIN ( SELECT InterestRate 
       FROM table 
       WHERE Id = oppId 
         AND Term = maxTerm 
         AND LoanAmount = maxAmount) b 
GROUP BY Id
```

This doesn't seem to work so if anyone has a way to acomplish this it would be fantastic!

Comment: What do you mean "max(term), max(loanamount)"?  What if the same id does not have the maximum for both?  Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by id order by Term desc, LoanAmount desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by term desc, loan_amount desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```